# operator precedence: ! and await

Tags: javascript, syntax, safari, async-await, operator-precedence

In JavaScript, how is the following statement to be interpreted:

```
cond1 && !await f()
```

This is an excerpt from the line

```
if(cond1 && !await f()){
    do_stuff();
}
```

inside a production application. chrome seems to be fine with it, but on ios this causes an error reading

```
unexpected identifier 'f'. Expected ')' to end an if condition.
```

It looks as if ios turns `!await f()` into `(!await)(f())` instead of `!(await f())`.

Now to my question: **According to [ECMA-262](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions) what is the correct interpretation of the above line?**

p.s.: We have fixed the code for ios by changing it to

```
var f_result = await f();
if(cond1 && !f_result){
    do_stuff();
}
```

Comment: It looks like your ios JS engine just doesn't support async/await yet. What app (browser) version are you using specifically?

Comment: @Bergi well, our production ios devices happily doing async/await are saying otherwise. They only choke on this exact statement.

Comment: @Bergi about the version: that would be the current one. 10.3. http://caniuse.com/#search=await

Comment: It appears to be a bug then. Report it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with operator precedence. Since both are unary prefix operators, there's only a single way this expression can be interpreted - all of `delete`, `void`, `typeof`, `+`, `-`, `~`, `!` and `await` are parsed with the same production goal and can be arbitrarily nested. And yes, it's valid syntax in ES2017.